# js force page into iframe - will google crawl it?

Tags: javascript, search, iframe, google-search

I have a script that reloads a blog page if its not in an iframe on my site. Will this interfere with search engines crawling the blog?

My gut says that this script won't keep the blog from being crawled, but it will interfere with any resulting links generated by search engines as following them, as these links will dump the user with js, into the 'top level' of the blog, and not the page they were after. To solve this would require some fancy cookie work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (self.location == top.location && location.search.substring(1) != 'nf')
 top.location.href = 'http://www.parentSite.co.uk/cms/section/iframe/'
</script>
```

what say ye?

Comment: In my experience, this may well get you excluded from Google's index. I worked on a site where a script like this was used and exactly that happened. Don't do it!

Comment: is there any way to test if google balks - other then say waiting a week to see if new content shows up in a search?

Answer (score -1):

Search bots, as I understand it, do not interpret JavaScript at all, so I think that's fine.

Although I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. It seems as though it would interfere with your users' experience quite a bit. Is there no way that you can load the content you want into the iframe on the parent page? perhaps with this `nf` parameter in your query string?

Comment: On the contrary, all modern search engines have a plethora of techniques to identify and punish sites that attempt to trick search spiders. In this case, the trick seems harmless, but what if it was a redirect to some completely different site? I cannot provide a citation, but surely this is the #1 used as well as combatted search spam technique.

Comment: I've read a variety of posts that cite that search bots dont follow js links etc - the levels of complexity were too great. SEO was cited as a reason not to have js links.

Comment: the site in question runs off a CMS, and the page Im trying to load within it is a stand alone blog - the cms dosen't offer an integrated blog  hence the iframe. 

We dont want people accidentally going to the blog through a search engine link and missing the site as a whole.

At the moment following SE links will dump the user into the top of site, 
but I figure that this could be sorted with a js cookie. Its a bit beyond me at the moment though. 

www.astonesthrowaway.co.uk is the site in question.